# Re-sampling groups of variable lengths so that group lengths are equal (R, dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set where the number of rows among groups can vary. I need to randomly sample with replacement within each group so that the number of rows is equal to a predetermined value.

Below I have an example `DATA` and desired `RESULT` tables. In this example, I need to randomly sample each group so that each `SITE` has 4 rows. Additionally, because `SITE$A` already has 4 rows, it should not be re-sampled.

Please note how the `RESULT` table retains the order of data across the columns of `STUFF:STUFF3`. I would prefer an answer using `dplyr`, because I use this package extensively, but I am open to other solutions.

```
  NUMBER = 4

    DATA = data.frame(SITE = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"),  
                      STUFF = c(1, 2, 30, 40, 100, 200, 300, 5000, 6000),
                      STUFF2 = c(2, 4, 60, 80, 200, 400, 600, 10000, 12000),
                      STUFF3 = c(4, 8, 120, 160, 400, 800, 1200, 20000, 24000))



   RESULT = data.frame(SITE = c("B","C","C"), 
                    STUFF = c(200, 5000, 5000),
                    STUFF2 = c(400, 10000, 10000),
                    STUFF3 = c(800, 20000, 20000))
```

I have tried various iterations of the code below.....without success. Thanks in advance.

```
RESULT = group_by(DATA, SITE)%>%
  sample_n(NUMBER - length(.), replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: `group_by(DATA, SITE)%>%sample_n( 4, replace = TRUE)`

Comment: Your code re-samples `SITE$A`, which should not be re-sampled.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you want to retain all the existing data, `sample_n` might be a wrong choice.

Comment: Maybe, but 'sample' does not work either. The main issue appears to be incorporating the variable lengths  of the groups into the `sample_n` `size` argument (e.g., 0 for `SITE$A`, 1 for `SITE$B`, and 2 for `SITE$C`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, `RESULT` is some kind of a complement data frame to `DATA` such as when combined together they would produce 4 rows for each group.

```
NUMBER <- 4

set.seed(1234)

RESULT2 <- DATA %>%
  group_by(SITE) %>%
  mutate(n = n(),
         sampsize = as.numeric( ifelse(n>=NUMBER,0,NUMBER-n)) ) %>%
  do( sample_n(., size=.$sampsize[1], replace=TRUE ) ) %>%
  select( -n, -sampsize ) %>%
  ungroup()

RESULT2
```

which produces this:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

  SITE STUFF STUFF2 STUFF3
1    B   100    200    400
2    C  6000  12000  24000
3    C  6000  12000  24000
```

If the full dataset is needed instead (the one that combines both `DATA` and `RESULT` into one data.frame with particular sorting requirements) then the following can be used:

```
NUMBER <- 4

set.seed(1234)

RESULT3 <- DATA %>%
  group_by(SITE) %>%
  mutate(n = n(),
         sampsize = as.numeric( ifelse(n>=NUMBER,0,NUMBER-n)) ) %>%
  do( rbind(.,sample_n(., size=.$sampsize[1], replace=TRUE )) ) %>%
  select( -n, -sampsize ) %>%
  ungroup()

RESULT3
```

which produces this:

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]

   SITE STUFF STUFF2 STUFF3
1     A     1      2      4
2     A     2      4      8
3     A    30     60    120
4     A    40     80    160
5     B   100    200    400
6     B   200    400    800
7     B   300    600   1200
8     B   100    200    400
9     C  5000  10000  20000
10    C  6000  12000  24000
11    C  6000  12000  24000
12    C  6000  12000  24000
```

Note that if `NUMBER` is smaller than the number of records in a group `RESULT3` will display the entire group unmodified.

Comment: It always comes down to the `do` function!!! Thanks! I wrote some very similar code to yours that would not work....but I did not incorporate the `do` function. I also slightly modified your code by wrapping the `sampsize` calculation into a single line without the `ifelse` statement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of @akhmed code that combines the `mutate` statements. I gotta get better with the `do` function in `dplyr`. Thanks.

```
RESULT4 <- group_by(DATA, SITE) %>%
      mutate(sampsize = NUMBER - n())%>%
      do (sample_n(., size = .$sampsize[1], replace=TRUE )) %>%
      select(-sampsize ) %>%
      ungroup()
```